# http proxy for debugging purposes

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, firebug

I am looking for a preferably free http proxy to be used for debugging purposes.

I already have firebug and firebug lite in my tool set, but firebug lite won't let me see ajax requests in internet explorer.

I thought an intercepting proxy might do the feat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).
It lets you track all of the HTTP traffic coming in and out of your application, break in the middle in order to change parts of it, log everything, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another simple HTTP proxy tool is [Don's Proxy](http://donsproxy.moneybender.com/).

> ... unlike other similar tools,
>   DonsProxy provides the ability to see
>   HTTPS traffic in its unecrypted form
>   by acting as a terminus for the
>   client-side connection, and
>   establishing a new secured connection
>   with the target service. This is done
>   with full knowledge of the user, so
>   that it does not introduce a security
>   breach.
>
> Sessions within DonsProxy are
>   instrumented with JMX, providing
>   visibility to the state of sessions'
>   read buffers and some other
>   information.
>
> While implemented in Java, this tool
>   can be used by developers building
>   networked applications in any
>   environment.

Comment: Just FYI: Fiddler can do SSL, too.  You need to configure it to do so. The doc is pretty straightforward.