# Arduino ethernet shield make a get request but no response

Tags: http, get, arduino

I would like my arduino to send a get request to a uri I have on my local network.  I can open a browser and manually paste the request in and it works.  I have also made the same request on a webpage using jQuery again no problem.

I have followed the tutorials for the Arduino and I can't see what I am doing wrong if some could help would be very grateful.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress server(192,168,0,34);

// Set the static IP address 
IPAddress ip(192,168,0,177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
// Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
Serial.begin(9600);
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

// give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
delay(1000);

}

void loop()
{
 Serial.println("connecting...");

   if (client.connect(server, 81)) {
   Serial.println("connected");

   client.print("GET /tenHsServer/tenHsServer.aspx?t=ab&f=ToggleDevice&d=");
   client.print("E3");
   client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
   client.println("Host: 192.168.0.34");
   client.println(""); //mandatory blank line 
 } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of issue you should learn about web debbugging tools. My favourite is [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/). However it is only available for windows. For other plattforms search the net for [http debug proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831450/http-proxy-for-debugging-purposes). Besides that there is always [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [ncat](http://nmap.org/ncat/).

Once you have such a tool in place just have a look at the generated traffic and compare it with traffic that actually worked. This usually allows to pinpoint the issue rather quickly.

Comment: ok I have installed wireshark and had a look The arduino code doesn't post a get request!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  packets go back and forth but not GET!!!!  My copied url into a broswer you see the get as clear as day!!!  how can this be I don't understand at all.  if you click on this link you can see a screen capture https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/102059869/example.jpg

Comment: So you found out that the issue is not the format of the request but that the Arduino does not issue any request at all. So the next step is to get ANY example that actually works with your setup. Did the ethernet shield come with any examples that work on your hardware?

Comment: The code I have created is from an example on the arduino site??  will have to keep digging.